# How can I get specific number of data in XML using Nokogiri gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can get the first two `<quake>` data in the XML using Nokogiri?

The data is arranged by date in **DESCENDING ORDER** (eq_date).

I already got the first `<quake>` data, but I plan to use the **first two(2) LATEST** for displaying purposes.

```
<quakes>
    <quake>
      <eq_date>1449528341</eq_date>
      <epicenter_code>191</epicenter_code>
      <magnitude>39</magnitude>
    </quake>

    <quake>
      <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>
      <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>
      <magnitude>44</magnitude>
    </quake>

    <quake>
      <eq_date>1449371999</eq_date>
      <epicenter_code>797</epicenter_code>
      <magnitude>42</magnitude>
    </quake>

    <quake>
      <eq_date>1449293419</eq_date>
      <epicenter_code>287</epicenter_code>
      <magnitude>38</magnitude>
    </quake>

    and more.........
</quakes>
```

Comment: Please edit your question. All your `<quake>` blocks are the same and you didn't explain exactly what should be the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<quakes>
  <quake>
    <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>
    <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>
    <magnitude>44</magnitude>       
  </quake>

  <quake>
    <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>
    <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>
    <magnitude>44</magnitude>       
  </quake>

  <quake>
    <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>
    <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>
    <magnitude>44</magnitude>       
  </quake>

  <quake>
    <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>
    <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>
    <magnitude>44</magnitude>       
  </quake>

  and more.........
</quakes>
EOT
```

Once the document is parsed it's easy to find all occurrences:

```
quakes = doc.search('quake')
quakes.size # => 4
```

Then it's easy to grab specific ones:

```
quakes[0].to_xml # => "<quake>\n    <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>\n    <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>\n    <magnitude>44</magnitude>       \n  </quake>"
quakes[1].to_xml # => "<quake>\n    <eq_date>1449505356</eq_date>\n    <epicenter_code>471</epicenter_code>\n    <magnitude>44</magnitude>       \n  </quake>"
```

Or, you could iterate over `quakes`, which is a NodeSet and behaves similar to an Array.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I got it, just get by index.

```
@xmlData = Nokogiri::XML(open('/index.xml'))
@xmlData.css('quake')[0]
@xmlData.css('quake')[1]
```

Comment: Don't do that. You're forcing a search each time. In a long or complex document that could be costly if you're retrieving multiple data.

Comment: Hi @theTinMan,Thank you for checking. So the best way to do it is like : @xmlData.search('quake').
Then, get the value by index?

Comment: It's explained in the answer I added. Also, we don't name variables using camelCase in Ruby. Use snake_case. It's the convention used by the community for readability and maintenance, so `xmlData` should be `xml_data`. Don't assume it's programmer choice because in a code review you'd get dinged.

Comment: Hi @theTinMan.
I understand, thank you very much for saying my mistakes. I got new knowledge.